# Symfony2 accessing kernel from a helper to use console command

Tags: symfony

To access console command from controller all I have to do is

```
$kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);
```

Now how can I do that from a different class like helper that does not extends Controller class. I do not want to inject the entire container into the helper class.

Comment: what do you want to inject exactly ?

Comment: $this->container->get('kernel'); I think.

Comment: This question is based on this symfony doc. [https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html]

Comment: So what's the problem if you inject the entire container? Even though you would do that, only the object you request will be instantiated (in this case only `kernel`), and not all objects inside the container.

Comment: Could it be done using by extending ContainerAware, and how would I go about that?